# XML output contains duplicate values after creating it using C# Linq to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Here is my code for creating an XML file

```
public void CreateXml(string[] names, string[] values, string type)
{
        XElement xml = new XElement("Transaction",
            new XElement("TransactionType", type));
        foreach (var i in names)
        {
            foreach (var o in values)
            {
                xml.Add(new XElement(i.Replace(" ", string.Empty), o));
            }
        }
        xml.Save("C:\\Users\\PHWS13\\Desktop\\sample.xml");
}
```

And my output looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Transaction> 
    <TransactionType>Void</TransactionType> 
    <Zip>1</Zip>
     <Zip>2</Zip> 
     <PNRef>1</PNRef> 
     <PNRef>2</PNRef> 
 </Transaction>
```

But it is not right, I am expecting more like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Transaction> 
    <TransactionType>Void</TransactionType> 
    <Zip>1</Zip>
     <PNRef>2</PNRef> 
 </Transaction>
```

As I have noticed the values are correct but it i just duplicates, How can I fix this?

```
string[] textBoxNamesArray = flowLayoutPanelText.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                                  .Select(r => r.Name)
                                  .ToArray();

string[] textBoxTextsArray = flowLayoutPanelText.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                                  .Select(r => r.Text)
                                  .ToArray();
```

Comment: Your problem lies here. foreach (var i in names)
        {
            foreach (var o in values)
            {
YOu might want to send them as dictionary type object or a collection of objects. And then do a single loop over the dictionary or collection.

Comment: @ryadavilli, any ways how to do that? thanks!

Comment: dasblinkenlight has given good explanation and a work around below. I have given a simple explanataion of how to use a dictionary below in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use two nested loops then: two nested loops create a *Cartesian product* (i.e. every name is paired up with every value).

If you use a single loop that goes through names and values at the same time, you'd get your expected output.

If you are using .NET 4, you could use `Zip` method, like this:

```
xml.Add(
    names
    .Zip(values, (n,v) => new XElement(n.Name(" ", string.Empty), v))
    .ToArray()
);
```

Comment: the n,v those are the arrays?

Comment: @GrayFullBuster No, these are parameters of the lambda - the second arg of the `Zip` method. It describes how to pair up names and values into a single temporary object, which is used in the next step to construct `XElement`. **EDIT** By the way, I simplified the expression some more to remove the `Select` and the use of an anonymous class.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to tell without knowing how you structure the data in your 2 arrays, but I would guess:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++)
    {
        xml.Add(new XElement(names[i].Replace(" ", string.Empty), values[i]));
    }
```

Comment: the sure thing about the two arrays is that they will always have the same length :)

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that this isn't obvious, only you know that ;-). Much better to only have 1 collection of objects that each have 2 properties.

Comment: @GrayFullBuster I have given a workaround in my answer if you are sure about your array lengths and values. But that is still not a very good way of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

Try this using a dictionary.

```
public void CreateXml(Dictionary<string, string> myNameValuePairs, string type)
{
    XElement xml = new XElement("Transaction",
        new XElement("TransactionType", type));
    foreach (var key in names)
    {
        xml.Add(new XElement(key.Replace(" ", string.Empty), myNameValuePairs[key]));
     }
    xml.Save("C:\\Users\\PHWS13\\Desktop\\sample.xml");
}
```

Edit: Workaround using your method signature as above. But this works if an only if values[i] is the corresponding value for names[i]. I would not advise this unless you are sure about the array lengths and contens of names and values.

```
public void CreateXml(string[] names, string[] values, string type)
{
    XElement xml = new XElement("Transaction",
        new XElement("TransactionType", type));
    foreach (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
    {
        xml.Add(new XElement(names[i].Replace(" ", string.Empty), values[i]));
    }
    xml.Save("C:\\Users\\PHWS13\\Desktop\\sample.xml");
}
```

Comment: I was trying to use the dictionary thingy. I got confused, where should I put the two arrays :)

Comment: Well, the place where you are creating your names and values arrays, I am sure you are doing name[i] = 'some name' and value[i] = 'some value'. Instead create your dictionary object there and do a dictObject.Add('some name', 'some value'); and then pass the whole dictObject to your method.

Comment: @ryadivilli, I put the code how I pass the values to an array